# Why am I getting this simplejson exception?

Tags: python, django, exception, simplejson

Why does Django give me this exception

```
[(7, u'Acura'), (18, u'Alfa Romeo'), ...] is not JSON serializable
```

When I try

```
data = VehicleMake.objects.filter(model__start_year__gte=request.GET.get('year',0)).values_list('id','name')
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False), mimetype='application/json')
```

?

It's just a simple list of tuples. It works with my other hard-coded list that's in almost exactly the same format. Is it because the strings are unicode? How do I handle that?

---

It works fine when I encode it as a dict:

```
def get_makes(request):
    year = request.GET.get('year',0)
    data = VehicleMake.objects.filter(model__start_year__lte=year, model__stop_year__gte=year).order_by('name').distinct().values_list('id','name')
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(odict(data), ensure_ascii=False), mimetype='application/json')
```

Some makes have accented characters... could that be it? Yes, the list is big (~900 makes total).

Comment: simplejson can handle Unicode strings just fine.  Can you show us the full data?

Comment: @Ned: There are about 900 entries.... and it was a b**ch to mine, so no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False), mimetype='application/json')
```

Use `list(data)` and modify your Javascript to work with it.

```
for(i in values) {
    $select.append('<option value="'+values[i][0]+'">'+values[i][1]+'</option>');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work fine:

```
In [28]: a = [(7, u'Acura'), (18, u'Alfa Romeo'),]

In [29]: simplejson.dumps(a, ensure_ascii=False)
Out[29]: u'[[7, "Acura"], [18, "Alfa Romeo"]]'
```

So it's not the first couple of tuples.  You'll need to dig deeper in the records list to narrow down the issue.  If it's large, perhaps take some slices of the data list and try encoding those, to see if the error occurs in any particular segment.

UPDATE:  OK, it's probably because your `data` object is a QuerySet and simplejson doesn't handle that.  Try using django's [serialize](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#id1) instead.  (Or coerce the data to a list.)

```
from django.core import serializers
json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
json_serializer.serialize(data, ensure_ascii=False, stream=response)
```

Comment: I guess `stream` should be `sys.stdout`?

Comment: You can use stdout and it will dump the output there.  But in a view, it should be a response object (response = HttpResponse()) and then you can simply "return response"

Comment: The `json_serializer` doesn't actually work. It doesn't like a `QuerySetValueList` either. And coercing data to a list yields weird results... `<option value="0">7,Acura</option>` (notice the `7` is in the name too). The json I get is `[[7, "Acura"], ...` which I *think* it supposed to use `{` s somewhere in there instead?

Answer (score 1):

[Ticket #6234](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6234) claims that leaving out `ensure_ascii=False` will resolve the problem (but I am not sure if the problem is really understood):

> Simply omitting ensure_ascii parameter resolves the issue even though it makes no sense.

Comment: Nope. Originally had it without. Thanks tho.